# NSNumberFormatter stringFromNumber: doesn't return a currency symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency, nsnumberformatter

I have the following method on a custom UITableViewCell subclass:

```
- (void)setPrice:(NSNumber *)price {
  _price = price;
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
  formatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
  formatter.currencyCode = @"USD";
  formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
  priceLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:_price];
}
```

`priceLabel` ends up displaying `_price` without a currency symbol ($). As far as I can tell, this shouldn't be happening. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the constant `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`? Objective-C doesn't have type checking for enumerations, but you can see from the name that it's a related to NSNumberFormatterStyle.

`formatterBehavior` takes a `NSNumberFormatterBehavior`, which is something like `NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault`.

You want to set `numberStyle` instead:

```
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
formatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
```

to:

```
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```